# Do I run significant risks by having my API called as HTTP rather than HTTPS?

Tags: http, security, ssl, api-design

I have a GET API that is called by a JS snippet to offload some computation from the browser. There is no reason that any actual user would directly call the API (and would be a violation of our ToS if they did).

Is there a significant risk if we call this API as a http request rather than https? It should reduce our response times, however we're not sure if this represents a vulnerability to either us or our users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the risk of non SSL login forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638745/understanding-the-risk-of-non-ssl-login-forms)

Comment: Unless you're running your API on an exceptionally under powered computer I highly doubt you'll notice a difference in response times.

Comment: "It should reduce our response times" Are you sure? Did you measure it? Or is it just "intuition"?

Comment: my profiler has about 150 calls of [method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects] that eats up a good chunk of response time. Is that likely from it being a https request or have I missed the true problem?

Comment: omg, violating the TOS :-) Juridic protection has nothing to do with engineering problems. If your data is free to read and alter/replay while it goes through the Internet, a jurist wont help.

Comment: On x86-64 architecture based computers, 150 library calls costs about 300 to 7500 clock cycles, depending of the type of calls (near jumps vs far jumps). A call is just a change of the stack pointer and some data pushed on the stack. The duration of the 150 calls is less than 10 micro secs at most, and with near jumps and compiler optimization, it certainly takes less than a microsec. What is done during those calls makes use of specific hardwired instruction sets like AESNI, I can’t believe this takes time that can be compared to half a millisecond or more, that is the network latency.

Answer (score 2):

If you make `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` requests to your HTTP API from HTTPS pages you will get [mixed content errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Comment: Hmm, ok, and just to check I'm diagnosing the right problem here, my profiler has about 150 calls of [method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects] that eats up a good chunk of response time. Is that likely from it being a https request or have I missed the true problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You risk MITM attacks or Man-in-the-middle. Someone impersonating your server and spying on your client's request and even potentially changing them.